# Detect which AnimationEnd has fired via animationName

Tags: javascript, css, detect, css-animations, keyframe

I have several CSS3 animations linked to one div, but I only want a function to be callad a the end of the last animation.

I have used the animationEnd event so that I can trigger said function but as I said I only want the it to run on the last animation.

Is there a way to detect with animation has ended by checking the name of the animation that has triggered the animationEnd event?

thus allowing me to use a if statement to single out the last animation.

Comment: Um, you answered your own question: Check the name of the animation tha triggered [the `animationEnd` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-events).

Comment: `if (event.animationName === "myAnimation") ...`

Comment: Argh! I couldn't feel more stupid. Must be this summer heat.

Thankyou Ray

Comment: This works fine in webkit but doesn't work in Firefox. Getting the "event isnt defined" error.

Comment: Um, it's the name of the parameter passed to your handler. Did you declare your handler correctly?

Comment: Have added the code im using to the main question.

Comment: Is the error message still "event isn't defined" for all three versions? Since your third version did define it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter is required when you define the function. Either of these should work;

```
var $element = $('.eye').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function(event){
     if (event.originalEvent.animationName === "three") {
         console.log('the event happened');
     }
}
```

Or,

```
var $element = $('.eye').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function(e){
     if (e.originalEvent.animationName === "three") {
         console.log('the event happened');
     }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can bind multiple conditions like that. Does this help: http://jsfiddle.net/HeX5E/

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why... but I can catch the the `animationName` only by **`e.originalEvent.animationName`**

so the best option is:

```
function getAnimationName(e) {
  if(e.animationName != undefined) return e.animationName;
  if(e.originalEvent.animationName != undefined) return e.originalEvent.animationName;
  else return undefined;
}
```

Comment: I think if you're using jQuery, then the event is all jQuery-ified, so you have to access the original event to find the animationName property.